# Exchange Information Store keeps restarting event ID 7024

Tags: exchange, vmware-esxi, exchange-2010, virtual-machines, service

My problem is as mentioned above that the exchange information store keeps restarting.
I am running Exchange 2010 SP2 on 2008 R2 as a VM

The event log shows the following entry realted to this:

```
Event ID 7024
The Microsoft Exchange Information Store service terminated with service-specific error %%-2147221213.
```

I have assured that the mailbox database is in an correct state and that there is no antivirus Software interfering.
As always all help will be apreciated :)

Comment: Any particular reason you're not running SP3, or more preferably SP3 RU1? The updates usually fix these bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this running on a VM?  The internal clock could be skewed (common for this error) and not in line with a DC.

Check your clock skew.  Make sure the time isn't being set/synced by the hypervisor/VMWare itself but instead by a local DC.

There should be an application event log error as well stating that the time could be off.

Comment: Yes that was the Problem exactly 
Tuning on Ntp on the ESX Host and restarting the VM solved the problem
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but could be useful to someone else: 
I had exactly that trouble, and solved updating time on vmware host (and rebooting exchange).

Note: time sync from hypervisor was deactivated, and exchange server (after booting up) showed no time skew with DC.